# Model designer QGIS question - Function toggles

Tags: polygon, dissolve

I just recently started using the model designer and I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to switch between the paths the process goes through. As in some kind of toggle that would allow us at the beginning to decide what path would the process would take in the function tree.

For example I have a series of functions to process vector files and I want to have the choice of dissolving these at the beginning of the process or not too. Does anyone know of a way?